# Implementation of Social OAuth2 rest-framework for combining Django and social accounts

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework, oauth-2.0

I am currently working on a login mechanism for the web application. This is the separation of the front-end (Vue) + Django DRF back-end. And I wanted to use the Django-rest-framework-social-OAuth2 library to implement something identical that we can see e.g. in the Evernote application. The user can choose to start an account from scratch or login via Google. Ok, it's great that if I create an account on the Evernote website, I can immediately connect them to the Google account.

It is in this case how such communication would look on the side of Vue - Django if I wanted to do it from the beginning based on REST

My plan was as follows
The user establishes an account by completing the registration form

In this way I get a login, password, etc. in my Django User table

After logging in to the account, he sees his website and the option to connect
from Facebook. After choose this option and send a query

curl -X POST -d "grant_type=convert_token&client_id=<client_id>&client_secret=<client_secret>&back-end= & token=<backend_token>" http://localhost:8000/auth/convert-token

Reply:

```
{
    "access_token": "c3JQjkkAOx8d0ZSyEgP6Hyh2hX3R66",
    "expires_in": 36000,
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "scope": "read write",
    "refresh_token": "7qawsbmQHgOv5vYjzorAXOeA0d2vla"
}
```

Of course, before that, you get an access token from Facebook using the JavaScript SDK.
And now I have a problem. After such a transaction, a 2 account appears in the database....

When it comes to authorizing a user through an account from the User Django model, I do it with a query

curl -X POST -d "client_id=<client_id>&client_secret=<client_secret>&grant_type=password&username=<user_name>&password=" http://localhost:8000/auth/token

Everything works I get in response:

```
{
    "access_token": "hu7chDBxOl11eVkZJmWCXPs0DgkdcS",
    "expires_in": 36000,
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "scope": "read write",
    "refresh_token": "m6K7tBQbTLJMXNFQQqmDj2wKGUWjIV"
}
```

The problem is that I have 2 separate entries in the database in terms of user accounts and I do not really know how I can combine them together.

One created using an entry in the database and a second account using the curl query in which I indicate access_token along with the backend. I would like to do it according to good practices. I see that these methods for logging in is a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a common issue with Oauth. You do end up with multiple entries in your database. If you want to fix this you have to detect the potential duplicate when you are about to create the duplicate (so you never have a duplicate) and give the user a chance to say that they own the first account.

Fixing duplicates afterward is cumbersome and may require notifying many users that you *think* there may be a dupe and prompt them to merge.